# C Best way of modifying values in a function

Tags: java, c, function, return, assign

I developed with Java since a few years, now I wanted to learn C and I noticed a few differences.

In Java when I want to return something from a function(e.g. read user input i would write

```
String s;
s = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

In C I would write

```
char s[20];
scanf("%d", name);
```

The difference is, in Java the function returns a value that can be assigned directly to a variable, while in C the function takes the variable name as an argument(respectivly the pointer to the variable).

I have noticed this with many C functions. When I write my own functions, should I do it like I'm used to in Java, or should I use the C style of assigning/returning values from functions?

Comment: you `c` code is trying to use uninitialized variable. try `char c` and `scanf("%d", &c)`

Comment: That question is too broad. It will be good for you to start working through the examples in a text book or an online tutorial.

Comment: @DimaMaligin I don't think that's true, at least not any more.

Comment: @unwind there was an edit in the question, before it was declared as `char *c`, and you can't use `c` without init/alloc

Comment: Yes, i edited the question, because I noticed my mistake

Comment: Some things in C and Java are very different, so much so that you should not try to find equal concepts or idioms.  Learn C as C, forget Java until you know how things are done in C. Once you have a decent grasp of C idioms, and the languages are more "equal" for you, then you can start comparing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest consideration in doing things in C only with return values is lack of exceptions. Unlike Java, where error conditions can be reported outside of regular call/return process, C has no such capabilities. In other words, `Scanner` has an option of throwing an exception when there is no next line; `scanf` does not have such an option.

If you would like to return an error status from your function, you are limited to (1) returning it in a static variable (not safe for concurrency), (2) returning it as the return value, or (3) returning it in a separate "error" object. Sometimes options (2) and (3) are combined.

As the result, you will often see C APIs that can fail structured like `scanf`, when the status is returned as the return value, and the rest of the values are modified through pointers.

```
if (scanf("%d%d", &i, &j) == 2) {
    ... // Got 2 numbers
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input! Expected two numbers.");
}
```

APIs that do not fail (say, `isalpha(ch)` or `tolower(ch)`) return their value directly.

Comment: But what should I use when I write my own functions? Or is it impossible to give a general answer to the question?

Comment: @danielr1996 When you write your own functions that can fail and must report status, use the `scanf` style. All input/output functions are in this category. When you write your own functions that do not fail because they handle all input values in *some* way, use the `tolower` style.

Comment: Ok, if i understand it right if anything can go wrong in the function i should return an error code or status code that gives information on the error/status, if nothing can go wrong i should return the value directly. Wouldn't it then also be possible(at least when i return a pointer) to return the value if everything went good and return a NULL pointer when the function failed(at least when it isn't necessary to distinguish between errors) like the malloc() function does?

Comment: @danielr1996 Returning pointers is a bit tricky because of ownership. There is no ambiguity with `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` because if you allocated it, you own it. If your function has a semantics that implies allocation (e.g. `strdup`) then it's definitely OK to indicate errors by returning `NULL`. In other situations you could use returning `NULL` to indicate normal course of action (e.g. `strtok_r`).

Comment: I blow my own horn, I really think that the biggest consideration is memory management, not error handling, that comes after.

Answer (score 2):

Java is object oriented and returns an object which is a pointer to the object.

In C you can return a pointer as well, but not an array. The C code you show is not correct because s, declared as a pointer to a char, is not initialized. Scanf expect a pointer to a preallocated buffer as second argument. It will write the input string into the buffer. I guess you meant `scanf("%d", s);`.

The C code you wrote will not work because s doesn't point to an allocated buffer to store the chars. You could define s as `char s[1024];` in which case s is equivalent to a pointer to a buffer of 1024 chars.

You could also define s a `char *s = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));` which will dynamically allocate the buffer for s. You then need to call explicitly free(s) to release the buffer when you don't need it anymore. This is because C doesn't have a garbage collector as in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Whereas in Java there is such a thing called a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), in C you are responsible of the memory management.

Java is **'give it to me'**.

```
String s = MyFunction();    // Give it to me.
```

In Java when you call a function that retrieve data from somewhere it just allocate it transparently and return it, the garbage collector will free it later.

C is **'put it there'**.

In C you have to manage the memory. The common practice is to first make some place to put the data then try to retrieve it.

Also your code should be more something like this:

```
char s[80];         // Static memory allocation, we hope it is enough.
scanf("%79s", s);   // Now we retrieve data. (Put it there).
```

Or something like this:

```
char* s = malloc(80 * sizeof(char)); // Dynamic memory allocation, we hope it is enough.
scanf("%79s", s);                    // Now we retrieve data. (Put it there).

// Do stuff with data 

free(s);                             // Be responsible.
```

So, **yes**, you should use the C style of assigning/returning values (it make sense, after all you are doing C).

One more point, if you code it like Java here what you will have:

```
char* MyTest() {
    char* a = "pipo";
    return a;           // Big fail, 'a' is local and will not exist anymore after return.
}

char* MyOtherTest() {
    char a[]= "pipo";
    char* b = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(b, a, sizeof(a));
    return b;           // My bet this one will never be freed.
}
```

That last example breaks a well know *good practice rule*, **the caller should be responsible of allocating/freeing the memory**.

The only exception I see is for *value type*, like simple type or struct.

```
// Nice and simple.
int MyAdd(int a, int b) { return a+b; }

// Why ? just Why ?
void MyAdd(int a, int b, int* r) { *r = a+b; }
```

Comment: In many cases, callee should be responsible for allocating, caller for freeing. Compare `getline` (POSIX.1-2008) and `fgets`, and consider which causes program to be buggy on unexpectedly long lines (or need to have complex logic to handle them properly, usually not implemented...).

Answer (score 2):

@DasBlinkenLight has an excellent point: **Sometimes you need the return value of a function to pass back an integer indicating an error occurred and what kind of error occurred.**

Another reason, as @chmike points out, is that if you wanted to return a string in this case, you would have to use `malloc()` (C's equivalent of Java's `new`). But C doesn't have garbage collection, so it must be explictly freed. Because of this, it is often "bad etiquette" to pass to other exterior functions a pointer that must be freed. **Who is to say that the programmer even wants memory to be allocated on the heap?** Using the heap is expensive, and often the whole reason the programmer is using C is because the program in question needs to be *fast*.

If the programmer who calls your function wanted to use the heap, they would do so in the case of `scanf` by calling `malloc()` themselves, then giving `scanf` a pointer to the new memory location which you could then fill with your function. That way the caller of `scanf` can keep track of all the memory that was allocated, and what memory was not.

When APIs *do* return allocated pointers, it's usually because it can't be avoided, and they explicitly document this and usually provide a function to free the memory properly, as is the case with [POSIX regex](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex)'s `regfree` or [glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html)'s `globfree`. This way, if the library does allocate the memory, the library also frees it.

Answer (score 1):

well, you should know the main difference between C and Java,

`Java` is `Object Oriented programming` while `C` is not.

in `Java` almost everything is `Object` ( except `primitives`).

The way you called `Scanner class` is a very bad approach,
you should do it as :

```
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
```

then call it to get string:

```
String s = scanner.nextLine();
```

The reason being is because everytime you call `new Scanner(System.in)` you assign your scanner to the same `Object` so it will start over from the start of the `System.in` meaning, you keep getting the same input over and over.

however in `C`, its not like this. since there its not an object you call.

So in short just remember in `java` everything is a `reference` (except primitive values of cource) to something else while in C its not the case

EDIT:
in terms of sending parameter to a method java can be tricky, because it depends on if you are sending a primitive data or an object.

for this reason it is normally better to get the method return something rather than sending the data that needed to be set as parameter

for example take a look at the scenario:

```
 1. Example 1

public void addOne(int i){
   i++;
}


public static void main(String... args){
   int i=0;
   addOne(i);
   System.out.println(i);
}

output= 0;

 2. Example 2


public int addOne(int i){
  return i++;
}

//output = 1


public static void main(String... args){
   int i=0;
   i = addOne(i);
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation, but that's not what I meant, I'm aware that java is OO and is C is not, the difference I'm wondering about is if should assign values with `value=function()` (the functions the returns the value and i can assign that value like in java) or with  `function(value)`(the functions writes it's values directly to the argument, of course the argument must be a pointer, like in c)

Comment: Correction: Java has support for object-oriented programming, C does not. Just because you are writing in Java doesn't mean your program automatically gets object-oriented design. And similarly, it is perfectly possible to use object-oriented design in C programs.

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot the `return` in front if `i++` in the second example, otherwise it would make no sense to write `i=addOne()` because the functions doesn't return anything?

Comment: @danielr1996 my appologies, yes I had forgotten.

Comment: I don't think scanner will read same stuff from stdin twice. It is not seekable, and I don't think there is any rewindable buffer provided by Java libs. Anything you read from stdin, is permanently removed from stdin.

Answer (score -2):

---

To read a char array in C, you first have to inialize the actual array with a limit of how long it can be. Somthing like this:

```
char str[20];
scanf("%s", &str);
```

Note the %s format string telling scanf to capture a string, %d is for integers.